# Switch between black and white background

Tags: javascript, background-color

Aim: switch background color between black and white by clicking one button.

The following is my code, which does not work.

```
<html>
<body id="pageBody">
<style>
body {background: #000000; color: #FFFFFF;}
</style>
<p>A sentence.</p>
<button type="button" onclick="changeBG()">Change BG</button>
<script>
function changeBG() {
    var bg = document.getElementById("pageBody");
    if (bg.style.backgroundColor=="#000000") {
        bg.style.backgroundColor="#FFFFFF";
        bg.style.color="#000000";
    }
    else {
        bg.style.backgroundColor="#000000";
        bg.style.color="#FFFFFF";
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just learn it from w3schools. How should I do?

Comment: `document.body` instead of getting the body element from an ID lookup.

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing against a hex string - the browser will return RGB values

`"rgb(0, 0, 0)"` for black and `"rgb(255, 255, 255)"` for white.

This will work:

```
function changeBG() {
    var bg = document.body;
    if (bg.style.backgroundColor=="rgb(0, 0, 0)") {
        bg.style.backgroundColor="#FFFFFF";
        bg.style.color="#000000";
    }
    else {
        bg.style.backgroundColor="#000000";
        bg.style.color="#FFFFFF";
    }
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FTSYF/

Comment: Your code works properly starting from the second click. I refresh the page, wait for more than 10 seconds, the first click still does not work.

Comment: @Kiddy because the background is initially white on the test page and not black like in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Use classes to make the code more reusable, and to avoid dealing with browsers changing color mode:

```css
body {background: #000; color: #fff;}
body.bg {background: #fff; color: #000;}
```

```js
document.body.classList.toggle('bg');
```

If you want it to work on old browsers that don't support `classList`, then use (assuming `body` doesn't have other classes):

```
document.body.className = document.body.className ? 'bg' : '';
```